# Бесконечный Stream со счетчиком и условием выхода

Tags: java, java-stream, java-8

Есть задача переписать цикл c вложенным условием выхода из цикла на стримы:

```
for(int i; i < 500; i++){
// обработка коллекции
   if(obj == 100){
        break;
      }
}
```

Я написал так:

```
public static List<DateBucket> bucketize() {
        return LongStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(500)
                .mapToObj(i -> {
                    // логика;
                })
                .toList();
    }
```

При этом я не понимаю, как добавить вложенное условие из цикла к стриму.

Или если написать так, то стрим работает бесконечно:

```
Stream.generate(() -> // логика)
                .takeWhile(r -> r.getI() == 100)
                .toList();
```

Comment: Что у вас источник обьектов? Стрим по `i` абсолютно лишний. Берете 500 обьектов из источника и стримите пока 100 не найдете через `takeWhile`.

Comment: источник объектов это результат работы внейшней функции к которой можно обратить максимум 500 раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по представленным фрагментам кода решение на Stream API должно выглядеть следующим образом, в `takeWhile` должно быть "обратное" условие по сравнению с оригинальным условием досрочного завершения цикла: `if (x == 100) break;` то же самое, что `while (x != 100) {...}`:

```java
public static List<DateBucket> bucketize() {
    return IntStream
        .iterate(1, i-> i < 500, i -> i + 1) // IntStream, цикл for
        .mapToObj(i -> getDateBucketAttempt(i)) // Stream<DateBucket>, логика для получения объектов
        .takeWhile(db -> db.getBar() != 100) // "обратное" условие для завершения стрима
        .toList();  // List<DateBucket>
}
```